# React Native on iOS crashes with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, react-native

That's `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'` on iOS with React Native.

Specifically `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller <UIViewController: 0x10542ddb0> that is already being presented by <UIViewController: 0x1053117d0>.'`

How could I troubleshoot this issue, debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using Firebase.

To fix

> **use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })**

Answer (score 0):

I had the app working. Then, I would shake and select "Debug with Chrome". The app would we be blank. I would re-install it through XCode. Then, I would get this error. The issue is that if I have react-native-reanimated, I should not use "Debug with Chrome"